# F5 Web GUI cannot be access

Tags: f5, big-ip

We have a pair of F5 running in HA (Active/Standby Mode). the problem is the F5 node 2 some interface (selfIP) can be ping, but cannot be SSH or connect via HTTPS. All are fine on F5 node 1 (primary). All the configure are in sync. i have try reboot them all, but same case

Answer (score 2):

you need to make sure the Self-IPs you are connecting to are configured to allow those ports, as self-IP configuration is device specific and is not synced.

Comment: The Port Lockdown is set to Allow All, is this setting what you mention before ?